# OSM version of gmplot

Tags: python, google-maps, openstreetmap

I used to use gmplot (the python module: https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot) to make html webpages with lat/lon points overlaid on google maps.

However, google maps is no longer free and as a result I want to switch to open street maps. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good alternative to gmplot which provides similar functionality which works with open street map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question.

The package folium works very well and supports osm and other map tiles. A tutorial can be found here: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/docs-v0.6.0/quickstart.html#Getting-Started